# Rx ForkJoin is not working with custom event

Tags: silverlight, system.reactive

I have some custom event args:

```
AutoOccurPerformedEventArgs : EventArgs
```

and the same event with these event args is raised in 2 seperate locations I'm trying to use the Reactive Extensions to forkjoin these and then subscribe

```
var events = new[]
                        {
                            Observable.FromEvent<AutoOccurPerformedEventArgs>(viewModel1, "AutoOccurActionPerformed"),
                            Observable.FromEvent<AutoOccurPerformedEventArgs>(viewModel2, "AutoOccurActionPerformed"),
                        };
events.ForkJoin().Subscribe(op => IsUpdatedByAutoOccur = op.Any(observedItem => observedItem.EventArgs.IsUpdatedByAutoOccur));
```

My anonymous delegate in the subscribe never gets called.  No exceptions are raised, the delegate just never gets invoked.

However, if I subscribe to each event individually, without ForkJoin, the events are handled correctly (although seperately)

```
Observable.FromEvent<AutoOccurPerformedEventArgs>(viewModel1, "AutoOccurActionPerformed")
                .Subscribe(o => IsUpdatedByAutoOccur = o.EventArgs.IsUpdatedByAutoOccur ? true : IsUpdatedByAutoOccur);

Observable.FromEvent<AutoOccurPerformedEventArgs>(viewModel2, "AutoOccurActionPerformed")
                .Subscribe(o => IsUpdatedByAutoOccur = o.EventArgs.IsUpdatedByAutoOccur ? true : IsUpdatedByAutoOccur);
```

Any ideas as to why ForkJoin is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the intellisense help on the `ForkJoin` method. Despite the spelling error, it says:

> Runs two observable sequences in parallel and combines their last elemenets.

Since you are doing a `ForkJoin` over events you will never get a result because these type of observables never complete.

You possibly want to use `Merge` or `CombineLatest` to achieve what you want, but since you didn't describe your intent I can't give a better suggestion.

Comment: I completely missed that.  Using both Zip and CombineLatest does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @Ciaran - Make sure that you're getting the semantics that you need. `Zip` can really quickly come unstuck if the two sources don't always produce values paired values. If one sequence produces even one extra value then `Zip` is always out of step. On the other hand `CombineLatest` will always produce two values if your two sources produce values in pairs and one of the two values will be a "previous value" & "current value" pair. It's not likely that both `Zip` & `CombineLatest` would work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Both *should* always produce values, but I may as well act defensively and use CombineLatest.  My use case is that I need a parent container to set an updated flag if either of it's children are updated in response to an event.

Comment: @Ciaran - In that case, give `Merge` a go. It sounds like a better choice. `Zip` is definitely the wrong choice. `CombineLatest` may give you incorrect behaviour if "A" fires and then, 10 minutes later, "B" fires - your app may think that the "A" event is current when it is not.

Comment: @Enigmativity - But if I use Merge and then subscribe, that will only give me 1 instance of my EventArgs, no? Or will the delegate get fired once for each event raised?

Comment: @Ciaran - `Merge` will fire for each value from the source observables. If "A" fires twice, but "B" only once, then "A.Merge(B)" will fire three times.